# Creating a file 'just in time' on a filesystem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems

I have a theoretical problem I'm trying to solve.

I have a system which can reference files on a local filesystem.  It can then parse those files and gather some data from them.  The file must already exist, even if it's empty.  The system will re-open the file every time the system comes on and at that point it would see values inside the file if they were added.

I need the data in this file to be different depending on who opens it. Everyone using the system will open the same file. A row level hack might work, where every open of the file acts as an append and each entry flags itself with some identifying key... so something like:

```
abc123 | hello | world
xyz987 | goodbye | earth
```

...would be OK where `abc123` and `xyz987` are the lock on the row used to provide row level security.

So, the act of opening the file is what determines what data gets put into it/returned from it.

The contents would be determined by some external service (REST, RPC, doesnt matter).

So, `open file => call some service which returns data => data gets put into file => return file handle`.  Actually putting the data into the file is optional as long as the data is accessible downstream.

I suspect this requires a change at the operating system level, so that the `read a file` process is actually an execution followed by an open.  That file can then be an executable shell script, just coincidentally named `file.json`.  When `read the file` happens, it can execute the script, which clobbers itself into a JSON response.  And then when the file is closed, it clobbers itself again into the magic shell script.

Similarly, making `file.json` a symlink which points either to a json file or to a shell script and having open know to set the link to one in order to execute and then set it to the other in order to open.

Is there anything like this which already exists?  Is there a better, more simpler, higher level way?  This is on a Linux system (Ubuntu) if that matters.  I'm envisioning it may evolve into a separate build with this hacky open trick added at the OS level but I'm hoping it's much simpler.  Language and such is open to anything.

Note:  this is trivial if the file was instead a web endpoint.  Having http://example.com/path/to/file.json do all of this is easy.  The problem is that it needs to be done at the filesystem level, presumably by the OS itself as it would do if you did `File > Open` for instance.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [FUSE](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse). It lets you easily implement your own FS in userspace (even [using Python](https://github.com/libfuse/python-fuse) if you want)

Comment: @thatotherguy I hadnt ever heard of FUSE but after reading up on it, I think that might be what I'm after.  Really glad something like this already exists.  Thank you for the suggestion.  If SO lets you make it into an answer (it might yell at you about no code or something?), I'll mark that as the solution.